# Correct approach of politely reply back with strong oppose

Tags: politeness, email

I asked for some details to one of my colleague. He replied and mentioned a special note in the reply mail. Something like this:

> Please find the detail below
>   1>aaaaaa
>   2>bbbbbb
>
> Please Note: we should not do that blah, blah, blah

so I want to reply back him on this mail **politely** but want to make sure that he should clearly understand that I am not happy for this special note and he should not put any special note (Suggestion) in future.

How can I say that. I am thinking to write something like ...

> Kindly do not put any special note instead of that.....

Is this ok? If someone can suggest me the tricky way to reply on this mail politely it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, and in general, I recommend against documenting (in email or otherwise) your dissatisfaction with your colleague's special note(s). This may prove problematic in the future. The "strong oppose" may be seen as confrontational, or *not playing well with others.* Also, http://workplace.stackexchange.com may be of help.

Comment: It's unclear what you want the coworker to do. He shouldn't ever express an opinion as to what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

Questions of professional interactions and possible repercussions aside, it sounds like you're asking how to phrase a *strongly-worded* note of reproach to a professional colleague? Something like this is usually acceptable:

> I would greatly appreciate it if you did not ...
>
> It might be better in the future if you did not ...
>
> I think that, going forward, it would be better if you did not ...

There are various others.  Of course, these might still cause unwanted friction with your coworker, but that's your choice.